# recomendaciones para el buen uso de querys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy haciendo uso de un query para la busqueda de registros, tengo  dos tablas, una es "venta" y la otra es "detallevet"(esta hace referencia a los detalles de la venta) mediante este query procedo a hacer la busqueda de las ventas en su modelo correspondient

```
  def self.busqueda_general(params)
  query = joins("left outer join detallevet on venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto and venta.RutaId=detallevet.RutaId")
                     .where("(venta.RutaId = :rutaId or :rutaId = '') AND (detallevet.Articulo = :articulo or :articulo = '')  AND (venta.CodCliente = :codcliente or :codcliente = '')",{rutaId: params[:search], articulo: params[:search3], codcliente: params[:search2]})
                     .distinct
  end
```

luego llamo dicho metodo en el controller en un metodo llamado busqueda_ventas

```
  def busqueda_ventas
   @detallevet = Detalleve.all
    @ventas = Vent.busqueda_general(params)

    respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    end
  end
```

las ventas estan relacionadas a los detalleventa pero no por un campo venta_id que los identifique, sino por medio de dos campos, uno llamado documento y otro RutaId en ambas tablas, ambas combinaciones deben de ser iguales para relacionarse. en mi vista estoy ordenando todas mis ventas con sus detalles respectivamente, para hacer esto en metodo del controller busque todas los detalle de esta forma @detallevet = Detalleve.all   y en la vista hice un render de la siguiente manera

```
<%= render `@detallevet.where(:Docto => vent.Documento, :RutaId => vent.RutaId) %>
```

al igual que para el mostrado de datos:

```
 <td><%=vent.IVA%></td>
        <td><%=@detallevet.where(:Docto => vent.Documento, :RutaId => vent.RutaId ).sum(:DescMon)%></td>
        <td><%=vent.TOTAL%></td>
        <td><%=@detallevet.where(:Docto => vent.Documento, :RutaId => vent.RutaId).count%></td>

        <td><%=@detallevet.where(:Docto => vent.Documento, :RutaId => vent.RutaId).sum(:Pza)%></td>
```

pero me parece que estoy haciendo uso de malas practicas colocando ese tipo de consultas en la vista, y de ser asi de que forma podria mejorarlo?

CODIGO ACTUALIZADO:

```
  has_many :detallevet, -> (vent) { where(Docto: vent.Documento, RutaId: vent.RutaId) },
           class_name: 'Detalleve'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el principal problema de tu implementación (aparte de no estar siguiendo el patrón MVC como corresponde haciendo la consulta en la vista), es que por cada venta estás realizando 3 consultas a la base de datos, provocando [3N + 1 consultas](http://apux.github.io/2014/02/10/como-solucionar-las-consultas-n-1-en-rails.html), siendo N la cantidad de ventas a mostrar (Ej: Si tu consulta `@ventas = Vent.busqueda_general(params)` te está retornando 20 registros, para mostrar toda la info en la vista terminaste realizando 61 consultas a la base de datos en vez de tan solo una).
Yo aprovecharía el join que estás realizando en `busqueda_general` y  agregaría todos esos sum y count que hiciste en la vista a la consulta (fíjate en el `select`):

```
  def self.busqueda_general(params)
    select("venta.*, COUNT(detallevet.*) AS venta_count,
            SUM(detallevet.DescMon) AS sum_DescMon,
            SUM(detallevet.Pza) AS sum_Pza")
      .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN detallevet ON venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto
              AND venta.RutaId=detallevet.RutaId")
      .where("(venta.RutaId = :rutaId OR :rutaId = '')
              AND (detallevet.Articulo = :articulo OR :articulo = '')
              AND (venta.CodCliente = :codcliente OR :codcliente = '')",
             rutaId: params[:search], articulo: params[:search3],
             codcliente: params[:search2])
      .group(:id)
      .distinct
  end
```

Luego en la vista llamaría las sumatorias y contador de cada venta, basándome en el alias que puse con `AS` dentro del `select`:

```
<td><%=vent.IVA%></td>
<td><%=vent.sum_DescMon)%></td>
<td><%=vent.TOTAL%></td>
<td><%=vent.venta_count%></td>
<td><%=vent.sum_Pza)%></td>
```

Para acceder a los detalles de una venta, simplemente pon un `has_many` con condiciones:

```
has_many :detalles, -> (vent) { where(Docto: vent.Documento, RutaId: vent.RutaId) },
         class_name: 'Detalleve'
```

luego llamas a:

```
vent.detalles
```

Comment: gracias por responder. intento colocarlo tal cual lo publicaste pero me salta un error en la terminal en la consulta, es el siguiente:   ActionView::Template::Error (TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near  ' * '.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT venta.*, COUNT(detallevet.*) AS venta_count,
             SUM(detallevet.DescMon) AS sum_DescMon,
             SUM(detallevet.Pza) AS sum_Pza FROM [venta] LEFT OUTER JOIN detallevet ON venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto
               AND venta.RutaId=detallevet.RutaId WHERE ((venta.RutaId = N''172'' OR N''172'' = '''')

Comment: @LuisC la verdad ni idea tengo de sql server, ya que nunca lo he usado, pero al parecer la sintaxis que pongas manualmente debe ir encerrada entre corchetes, algo como `select("[venta].*, COUNT([detallevet].*) AS venta_count`, tal como sale en las consultas [de esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24235451/895789)

Comment: gracias Alter, lo cambie de la forma en que me mencionaste y ademas le cambie a comillas simples y funciono, pero ahora me manda un error en el select, estoy intentando varias combinaciones para tratar de hacerlo funcionar, y he notado que si dejo el [venta].* no da dicho error

Comment: pero si ademas agrego los metodos count con la otra tabla me da el siguiente error: Column 'venta.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [venta].*, SUM([detallevet].DescMon) AS [sum_DescMon] FROM [venta] left outer join detallevet ON venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto'):

Comment: @LuisC ah claro, me faltó un `group`, sino, no funcionan los counts. Revisa mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: supongo que ese id en el group representa al Id de ventas cierto? lo agregue pero ahora me manda el mismo mensaje pero con otro campo que es RutaId:Column 'venta.RutaId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT [venta].*, SUM([detallevet].DescMon) AS sum_DescMon FROM [venta] left outer join detallevet ON venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto GROUP BY [venta].[Id]'):

Comment: debo de ir agregando todos esos campos al group?

Comment: @LuisC al parecer si que debes agregarlos. Por lo que leo en [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4611928/895789) en SQL estandar debes agregar c/u de los campos de la tabla cuando haces un `select * group by`, lo cual no es necesario en mysql o postgresql (al menos yo lo he realizado anteriormente en esos db engines y nunca me ha dado problemas). Quizás sql server se basa mas en el sql estándar en ese tipo de ocasiones, la verdad lo desconozco.

Comment: perfecto muchisimas gracias, si me funciono, en efecto tuve que agregar todos los campos. oye y respecto a la otra duda en la pregunta, que es la de renderizar todos los detalles de las ventas de esta forma <%= render @detallevet.where(:Docto => vent.Documento, :RutaId => vent.RutaId) %>    Supongo de igual forma que estaria mal por hacer el uso de las consultas en la vista, para desplegar esos datos haria uso de la misma consulta anteriormente planteada o ahi si seria necesario crear una consulta nueva para los detalles?

Comment: @LuisC no se a que código te refieres, no veo en ninguna parte algo como `<%= render @detallevet`, pero mientras menos ĺógica de modelo metas en las vistas o controladores, mejor. Y si es inevitable, trata de poner esa lógica en un helper por último.

Comment: es en el tercer codigo, ese lo utilizo para hacer un render de todos los detalles de cada venta, pero mi pregunta es si para si tendria que crear otro query para los detalles de cada venta o puedo renderizarlos directamente desde el query de busqueda_general

Comment: @LuisC ve la actualización

Comment: excelente muchas gracias, estoy intentando la forma de mostrar los detalles solo que tengo un pequeñisimo inconveniente. estoy colocando tal cual indicaste, solo que en vez de "detalles" coloque "detallevet" que es el plural de dicha tabla, ese codigo lo coloque en  actualizacion  en lo ultimo de mi publicacion en "CODIGO ACTUALIZADO".

Comment: En la vista estoy haciendo un pequeño render para mostrar todos los detalles con su venta respectivamente, de esta forma:             <% vent.detallevet.each do |d| %> <%= d.Articulo%> <% end %> pero me muestra este error: ActionView::Template::Error (TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name 'vent_id'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [detallevet].* FROM [detallevet] WHERE [detallevet].[vent_id] = @0 AND [detallevet].[Docto] = @1 AND [detallevet].[RutaId] = @2', N'@0 int, @1 int, @2 int', @0 = 710988, @1 = 16138782, @2 = 161):

Comment: me parece que esta buscando un campo llamado vent_id que es el que haria referencia a los detalles. pero dicho campo no existe debido a que los detalles y las ventas solo deben de relacionarse con los campos "RutaId" y  "Documento". faltaria algo en la relacion del modelo que me indicaste o estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: @LuisC creo que deberías crear otra pregunta, no puedes seguir infinítamente con esta sucesión de preguntas/respuestas en los comentarios, aparte que no es el lugar adecuado para poner código, estás mal usando la plataforma. La pregunta que realizaste ya la contesté según lo que preguntaste y si tienes inquietudes o problemas adicionales, puedes hacer otra pregunta, ya que hay mas usuarios de la comunidad que pueden contestarlas aparte de mi.

Comment: perfecto ya publique mi otra duda, muchisimas gracias Alter por ayudarme a corregir mi codigo, no tienes idea de cuanto me ha servido tu ayuda, muchisimas gracias amigo.